# Is there a way to find from where Angular is injecting a value?

Tags: angular, angular6

I know that in Angular there is a hierarchical dependency injection model with injectors at root and component level. Is there a way to find from where Angular is injecting a value? I am facing an issue. A wrong class is being injected in my application. I need to debug how Angular is resolving the dependency.

Comment: I think Augury can tell you that: https://augury.rangle.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the wrong class is being injected, then you may have a misconfigured module structure where some child injector (provider) is providing a different class to your Component.

You may want to look at the Angular.io Dependency Injection Documentation page. Specifically the part on [Injector Hierarchy and Service Instances](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injector-hierarchy-and-service-instances).

If you want to manually configure the provider(s) of your Service, then you can declare [explicitly where the class is provided](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#where-to-configure-providers) by using the `providedIn` property of the `@Injectable` annotation:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root', // or `providedIn: MyModule,`
})
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Or you could set the provider for your Service in the module in which you will inject the Service, like so:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: MyService, useClass: MyServiceAltImplementation }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, they want to know how to debug the injector state.

Comment: well, I found the answer but I had to manually debug it by inspecting each source file. The issue was indeed with the way `providers` were used. I had used `@Injectable({  providedIn: 'root'})` in the service's `.ts` file rather than in module's `.ts`. This caused quite an issue to me in configuring the `TestBed`!! Though the issue is resolved now, I would like to know if there is a way to debug using some tools.

Comment: Have you tried [Augury](https://augury.rangle.io/)? *Suggested by @jonrsharpe in a comment on your question.* It is a browser extension that allows you to inspect classes/objects in your running Angular code and do other helpful debugging tasks.